# How to display two button on same line alignment if button outside Edit form?

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-5, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I work on blazor app .NET core 7 . I face issue i can't display two buttons on same Line .

first button inside edit form for submit and insert data

second button outside edit form for clear data controls

How to display two button on same line .

my code

```
<EditForm>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:140px">
      Create
    </button>
                   
                  
                 
</EditForm>
               
                <button class="btn btn-primary align-top m-2" style="width:140px;"><i aria-hidden="true"></i> Clear</button>
```

Expected result
[image: two buttons not on same line]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enclose them in a row

```
<div class="row">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:140px">
  <button class="btn btn-primary align-top m-2" style="width:140px;"><i aria- 
  hidden="true"></i> Clear</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to enclose each button in an `<td></td>` also. I also wrapped the whole thing in a `<table>`